# Getting content from MySQL, print it and update without refresh NOT WORKING

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, get

**Hi,** well my computer is broken, and I'm using one that I can't install anything and I can't update Firefox version, so I can't check the errors from JS in the console (in Chrome it works)

Well... The problem is that the following code doesn't work and I don't know if its problem of Jquery or mine...

(I'm new on Jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setTimeout(function () {
    $.get("http://toomanydownloads.x10host.com/forum/custom/visits.php", function (data) {
        $("#visits").html(data);
    });
}, 1000);
});
```

So basically, on visits.php I request the data I want to show (the hits of the web (it's only a hit counter))... That text is showed at the end (footer) of the web (between a span tags and it close called visits)...

So what is wrong with that?

**Bye, thanks.**

Comment: Is CORS enabled? Is the Chrome console providing any information?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 12 (with a rooted (I can't install anything) Linux)

Comment: Firefox 12 has built-in dev tools, including a console.

Comment: Yes, but this console doesn't say anything about any error, can you check it in a min plz: http://toomanydownloads.x10host.com/forum/

Comment: I'm sorry, we're not likely to travel off-site to view a site to try and track down the issue. Can you provide a small example fiddle or some other test?

Comment: No, because the text I try to update is getted from a DB... And If I pass a fiddle, the same origin policy will disable it...